# Apply timeseries decomposition (and anomaly detection) over a sliding/tiled window

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, purrr, anomaly-detection

Anomaly detection methods published and now abandoned by [twitter](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection) have been separately forked and maintained in the [`anomalize` package](https://github.com/business-science/anomalize) and the [`hrbrmstr/AnomalyDetection` fork](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/AnomalyDetection). Both have implemented features that are 'tidy'.

*Working static versions*

```
tidyverse_cran_downloads %>% 
  filter(package == "tidyr") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-package) -> one_package_only

one_package_only %>% 
  anomalize::time_decompose(count,
                 merge = TRUE,
                 method = "twitter",
                 frequency = "7 days") -> one_package_only_decomp

one_package_only_decomp %>%
  anomalize::anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  anomalize::time_recompose()


one_package_only_decomp %>% 
  select(date, remainder) %>%
  AnomalyDetection::ad_ts(max_anoms = 0.02,
        direction = 'both')
```

These work as expected.

I would like to apply the twitter anomaly detection process on a tiled window to my dataset, which is similar in structure to the `anomalize::tidyverse_cran_downloads` dataset. A regular set of over 100 observations of a value, grouped by a categorical definition.

The `tsibble` package (which replaces the old `tibbletime`) has a method to apply a function in a `purrr`-like syntax via [slide,tile and stretch](https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/articles/window.html). This can include returning a full data-frame like object, inside another data-frame like object as per `purrr`. (What a sentence!)

I've gone through the [window function vignette](https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/articles/window.html) but haven't had much luck.

*Attempt 1 `slide2`*:

The `anomalize::decompose_twitter` function takes two arguments, `data` and `target`

```
tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
  mutate(
    Monthly_MA = slide2_dfr(
      .x = .,
      .y = count,
      ~ anomalize::decompose_twitter,
      .size = 5
    )
  )
```

`Error: Element 1 has length 3, not 1 or 425. Call`rlang::last_error()`to see a backtrace`

Maybe I've misunderstood how the `.x .y` syntax works?

*Attempt 2:`pmap`*

```
my_diag <- function(...) {
  data <- tibble(...)
  fit <- anomalize::decompose_twitter(data = data, target = count)
}

tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
  nest(-package) %>%
  filter(package %in% c("tidyr", "lubridate")) %>%  # just to make it quick
  mutate(diag = purrr::map(data, ~ pslide_dfr(., my_diag, .size = 7)))
```

`Error in stats::stl(., s.window = "periodic", robust = TRUE) : series is not periodic or has less than two periods`

Appears something is running, but the period between observations is off somehow or not getting parsed?

*Attempt 3: `ad_ts`*

`ad_ts` only takes one argument, so ignoring the fact that we have yet to find a way to calculate the remainder after decomposition, I should be able to use it via `slide`. It also expects it's `x` to be:

> Time series as a two column data frame where the first column consists of the timestamps and the second column consists of the observations.

So we shouldn't have to do much to the data after it's nested.

```
tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
  nest(-package, .key = "my_data") %>%
  mutate(
    Daily_MA = slide_dfr(
      .f = AnomalyDetection::ad_ts,
      .x = my_data
    )
  )
```

`Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : data must be a single data frame.`

So the function is at least being called, but it's being called by more than a single data frame?

I want to:

- Apply a process of decomposition through the twitter algorithm, followed by anomaly detection on the remainder
- Use one of the two anomaly detection packages to do it, or a blend of the two
- Apply it to a window of time
- Over grouped categorical data

The only way my data set differs is that I have *half hourly* observations of values over a *period of multiple months*, and I actually only need the anomalies recalculated each day (i.e. once every 48 observations), where the window looks back over the prior *30 days* to decompose and detect them.

(N.B. I would have tagged `tsibble` and `anomalize`, but I don't have the rep to make those tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 2 should work as expected? The error message is related to the `stl()` that requires at least two seasonal periods to estimate. For example, daily data needs at least 14 observations for `stl()` to run. Increasing the window size `.size = 7 * 3` works fine.

```r
my_decomp <- function(...) {
  data <- tibble(...)
  anomalize::decompose_twitter(data, count)
}

library(dplyr)
library(anomalize)
tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
  group_by(package) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  mutate(diag = purrr::map(data, ~ tsibble::pslide_dfr(., my_decomp, .size = 7 * 3)))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    package   data               diag                
#>    <chr>     <list>             <list>              
#>  1 tidyr     <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  2 lubridate <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  3 dplyr     <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  4 broom     <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  5 tidyquant <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  6 tidytext  <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  7 ggplot2   <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  8 purrr     <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#>  9 glue      <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#> 10 stringr   <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#> 11 forcats   <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#> 12 knitr     <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#> 13 readr     <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#> 14 tibble    <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
#> 15 tidyverse <tibble [425 × 2]> <tibble [8,506 × 5]>
```

Comment: It absolutely does. At some point I had apparently misunderstood/forgotten what the `.size` argument was doing (which is in fact, very clearly documented, and I had definitely read!). Thanks for your work on the package. Really useful.